# GCC/VS2008: Different behaviour of function call when templated base class is derived from itself

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, inheritance, gcc, templates

The following code works with Visual Studio 2008 but not with GCC/G++ 4.3.4 20090804. Which behaviour is - according to the C++ standard - correct?

```
template <int N>
struct A : A<N-1> {};

template <>
struct A<0> {};

struct B : A<1> {};

template <int N>
void Func(const A<N> &a) {}

int main()
{
    A<1> a;   //is derived from A<0>
    Func(a);  //vs2008: ok, g++: ok
              //Comeau: ok

    B b;      //is derived from A<1>
    Func(b);  //vs2008: ok, g++: error, no matching function for call to Func(B&)
              //Comeau: error: no instance of function template "Func" matches the
              //        argument list. The argument types that you used are: (B).

    return 0;
}
```

If I overload Func() with

```
void Func(const A<0> &a) { std::cout << '0'; }
void Func(const A<1> &a) { std::cout << '1'; }
```

always the latter one is called (as expected). So I would also expect the templated function to be called with N=1 because A<1> is direct base of B. Is this assumption really wrong?

Comment: Doesn't compile with Comeau Online either. What do you expect N to be in the second case (since b is convertible both to A<1> and A<0>)?

Comment: I think it is just another MSVC++ extension.

Comment: @UncleBens, wow i've not seen that `B` also inherits `A<0>`! Good eye :)

Comment: Notice that a direct call to `void f(A<0>); void f(A<1>); B b; f(b);` would succeed, because `A<1>` inherits `A<0>`, the `A<1>` is considered a better match. But during deduction, this does not matter as @UncleBens says: The compiler will yield two deductions and reject the template.

Comment: Yes, you can call `Func` specifying the template parameter, it will work. (e.g: `Func<0>(b)`).

Comment: Compiles with xlC 10. Calls Func<1> both times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some digging through N3035, I found this in section 14.9.2.1.4:

> If P is a class and P has the form simple-template-id, then the transformed A can be a derived class of the deduced A. Likewise, if P is a pointer to a class of the form simple-template-id, the transformed A can be a pointer to a derived class pointed to by the deduced A.

However in 14.9.2.1.5, it says:

> These alternatives are considered only if type deduction would otherwise fail. If they yield more than one possible deduced A, the type deduction fails.

Which is the case: both `A<1>` and `A<0>` are considered base classes for `B`.

I guess this means a no for Visual Studio (at least, if the current standard says the same: exercise for the reader).

Answer (score 0):

In ISO/IEC 14882 it's nearly the same (14.8.2.1):

> - If P is a class, and P has the form template-id, then A can be a
>     derived class of the deduced A.
>     Likewise, if P is a pointer to a class
>     of the form template-id, A can be a
>     pointer to a derived class pointed to
>     by the deduced A.
>
> These altenatives are considered only if type deduction
>   would otherwise fail. If they yield
>   more than one possible deduced A, the
>   type deduction fails.

So I agree with Jan. Anybody here who does not?

Comment: What could be the reason that it was specified this way?